# Get all kernel timers

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

Sorry for my English. I want to get all system timers (that check it's DPC), but I have already spend a lot of time - no result. I read MSDN (DDK documentation), but have found nothing. Help, please. (It's my homework in institute, no virus development)

Comment: [You can measure the amount of time that a driver spends in deferred procedure calls (DPCs) and interrupt service routines (ISRs) by tracing these events in the Windows kernel.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545764(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Ok, I can to do something from debugger, but I want to get results in my driver. (And use WinDDK)